# Behavior of an arraylist when adding to a specified index

Tags: java, arraylist

I know you can add objects to an arraylist at a specified index but I was wondering what happens to the indices before, after and between the objects placed at these indexes.

I am implementing an exam grading system and I have a Student getAnswers() method that retrieves all the answers provided by a student on an exam. I store it in an arrayList.

```
ArrayList<Answer> studentAnswers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

Now every answer knows the question number it corresponds to so within this arraylist i'd like to add the answers to the index specified by the questionNumber.

```
for(Answer s: getAnswers()){
studentAnswer.set(s.getQuestionNumber(), s);
}
```

My issue is that if the student didn't answer one of the questions, I want it to be a null answer. I don't know if this is the right way to handle that.
An example would be:

```
StudentAnswer [question 1, "Foo"]
StudentAnswer [question 2, "Class"]
StudentAnswer [question 4, "Object"]
```

And if the answer key was `["Foo", "Class", "Interface", "Object"]`

The studentAnswers list should look like this: `["Foo", "Class", Null, "Object"]`

Null because he didn't answer question 3.

I don't know if this is the right way to handle that.

Comment: Think about making the getAnswers() method return null if the student didn't answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an array rather than ArrayList would be better suited for this problem since you'll need to initialize the size of the array with your number of questions.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class StudentAnswer {
    private int id;
    private String value;

    public StudentAnswer(int id, String ans) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = ans;
    }

    public int getQuestionNumber() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentAnswer a0 = new StudentAnswer(0, "Foo");
    StudentAnswer a1 = new StudentAnswer(1, "Class");
    StudentAnswer a3 = new StudentAnswer(3, "Object");

    int totalQuestions = 4;
    StudentAnswer[] answers = new StudentAnswer[totalQuestions];
    answers[a0.getQuestionNumber()] = a0;
    answers[a1.getQuestionNumber()] = a1;
    answers[a3.getQuestionNumber()] = a3;

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(answers));
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
[Foo, Class, null, Object]
```

Note: The quotes won't display on the strings unless you modify the `toString` method in `StudentAnswer`.